# Text box height is bigger in IE8 (compatibility view only)

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

I have textbox which is rendered fine in Chrome, firefox and IE8(normal view). If i change the IE8 to Compatibility view, then the textbox is appearing bigger in height.

Please help me in fixing this.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

1st image is is in compatibility mode. 2nd image is in normal view

Comment: If your website is broken in compatibility view, then don't turn compatibility view on. It's designed to make broken webpages usable in new versions of IE. If yours ain't broke, it don't need the fix.

Comment: Do you have padding and margin? IE will calculate that differently.

Comment: in my corporate, the IE is shipped by default in compatibility mode. Some people will use chrome(which is same as IE 8 normal mode). So we are in a position to render properly in any of the modes...

Comment: The developer in me says it works in standards mode, don't muck with it... The usability expert in me says it should gracefully handle both modes because an end user has no idea about these modes... The ideologist in me is losing his mind because Microsoft added Compatibility Mode to bridge the gap for sites that weren't quite standards mode... and here you have a site that renders fine in the desired Standards Mode, but you're being forced to support an additional mode that you really shouldn't. Gahh! Worst of all you are forced into this mode due to an IE GroupPolicy that incorrectly applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange. I added the following css:

```
vertical-align: top;
line-spacing: 0px;
text-indent: 0px.
```

Now the textbox height is same in both the views.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to some weird padding IE adds. This worked for me:

```
padding: 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this in the <head>

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

Comment: No, you don't want to emulate IE 7 because the website works just fine in IE 8. It's compatibility mode (i.e., emulating IE 7 mode) that is broken.

Comment: I cannot force the page to render in IE 8 normal view. there is some group policy running in IE, that prevents this emulation. So even with this tag, the page is rendering in IE8 compatiblity mode only. The better solution would be to fix the box height in both modes.

Comment: @Raghav - actually, if it is possible, the "better" solution would be to not have an IE Group Policy that forces all sites into Compatibility Mode.  For sites that specifically require it, they should be added to the Compatibility Sites list - for everything else, let them render as designed in Standards Mode.  Forcing Compatibility Mode just continues making the global push for Web Standards more difficult because we keep needing to maintain backwards support.

Comment: Exactly. That would be a better option, but the policy is actually done through some Software Supply/Admin team. And it is happening only for the Intranet sites. Intranet sites are always running in compatibility mode, unless the user changes it manually.